# Create a VPN from code

Tags: c, powershell, ssis, vpn, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to create/destroy a VPN from a SSIS (script) package?
I know now how to start/end an existing VPN. But this means the VPN already has to be present on the system running the package. Is it possible to create a VPN from code, run it and then destroy it? Prefreably even create an object in the toolbox?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554824.aspx

Comment: How to answer can it be done: Can you code it now in C#/VB.NET or can you start it from the command line? If so, *then* yes, you can start it from SSIS. Can you create a toolbox object? Yes, assuming you were able to create it above. [Sample components](http://msftisprodsamples.codeplex.com/)